# How can I increase the screen resolution of Minecraft on a Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

When I maximize Minecraft on my Mac it just changes the size of the window, not the actual game. How can I get a higher resolution?

(Example):
[image]

I believe that is 1280x800px.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't increase the resolution of the Minecraft world, but you can make sure the interface elements don't scale upward.

As of Minecraft Beta 1.5, you can set the scale of the UI by going into *Options* → *Video settings...* and clicking on *GUI scale*.

If you leave *GUI scale* set to *auto*, it'll continue to use the old GUI scaling: if your window exceeds 1280x720, Minecraft scales the interface elements up with the window.

Comment: Wow that is really stupid. Is this something notch could fix?

Comment: @Lucas: either thing could be fixed by notch *per se*, but I wouldn't hold my breath for increasing the resolution of the Minecraft world: all the textures are incredibly low resolution and it's part of the game's character. The interface scaling is a relatively easy change (sjohnston's answer points to a mod that accomplishes it), and I'm sure notch could be persuaded to make adjustments to its algorithm. However, there are only two people working on the Minecraft product right now, and there's a million other things on their todo list.

Comment: @Lucas as of Minecraft Beta 1.5, you can now fix the scaling of GUI elements. The world is still low resolution.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a configuration option for this (on Mac or otherwise), but [this mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=63613) prevents the interface elements from scaling, even at large resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

Start the game and then press <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The textures are set to a certain resolution, so even though you're scaling your screen resolution, it will still look the same.  Notch designed Minecraft to look like an old 320 x 200 pixelated game. Because the game is currently just played in windowed mode (even when maximixed), you're just wasting processing power cranking up your screen resolution.  You can crank it down to 800 x 600 to increase your performance.

If you want nicer graphics/resolution, you can get a mod that uses higher res graphics. Using one of those then cranking up your screen res will make a difference.

Notch is eventually going to make the game like other commercial games, IE: when it starts, it goes into fullscreen mode and takes control of your computer's screen resolution.  This will allow you to set the res within the game itself.  But for now, we're all stuck with windowed mode, and have to mess with the screen res / apply graphic mods ourselves.

Comment: **Almost everything in this answer is wrong.** First, you can already play the game in full screen mode. Second, you actually can change the resolution via resizing the window. And performance in not a huge concern, I'm already getting close to 100 fps with render distance set to far, graphics on high quality, and the window maxed.

Comment: @Lucas You do not alter the resolution in any way by resizing the window, it stays just the way it was **but** your GPU scales, i.e. stretches the view to fill the window area.